# How to extract first element from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
        ods_file = io.BytesIO(response.body)
        df = read_ods(ods_file, sheet_name)
        df_one = df.apply(lambda c: str(c[0]).strip("[]"))
        print(df_one)
```

Result from print is:

```
[Report for: 02-Nov-2022]    N
unnamed.1                    N
unnamed.2                    N
unnamed.3                    N
```

How to extract only [Report for: 02-Nov-2022]?
I would be grateful if someone would correct my code and explain it to me

Comment: Please provide rest of the code for anyone to reproduce and help you

Comment: Can you show an example of your expected output, given your input?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element of the first column like this :

```
element = df_one.iloc[0,0]
```

check : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

for more details.